# How to disable keydown/keyup/keypress function in X seconds?

Tags: jquery, keypress, keydown, keyup

I want to disable function like `.keydown()` , `.keyup()` , `.keypress()` in some seconds.

Which jQuery function can I do this ?

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode==32) {
     $("code").append(".");
 }
});



setTimeout(function(){
        // ?????
},3000);
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/jpGm8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the event, bind it using `.on()` and remove it using `.off()`.

```
$(window).on( 'keydown.my', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==32) {
        $("code").append(".");
    }
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $( window ).off( 'keydown.my' );
}, 3000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jpGm8/2/

Comment: Yes ! Looking for this. Named function like this I never knew before :D